# Any reasons why my 18650s go very hot when I charge them?

Tags: lipo, charge

I have some PanasonXX 18650 batteries the grey and the green one

I charge them in 2.5A 4.3v but I found that the green battery is very hot after I charge it about an hour later, I don't know the exact temperature but I can barely use my hand to touch it because its very hot.

But at the same time all my grey batteries are just a little bit warm, any reasons for this situation? As I'm afraid it will catch fire.

Thank you[image]

Comment: STOP CHARGING THE GREEN BATTERY! They should not get "very hot". This is very dangerous.

Comment: I agree with the caution expressed, and you should stop with the green one.  You might **also** want to check one of the known-good batteries in that charger position to make sure there isn't a charger issue. That kind of charger has a lot of independent circuitry associated with each charger position.

Comment: Maybe 2.5A is too high a charge rate. There are different types of Li-ion batteries. The panasonics have good capacity but are not intended for rapid charge or discharge. When charged rapidly, the charger must monitor cell temp carefully and back off if it gets too hot.

Answer (score 1):

1. 2.5A is too high, charge current is 1925mA with 4.2V.
2. A charger should stop and alarm for high temperatures, does yours?

When batteries age the internal resistance increases, which will result in more heat when charging/discharging.
Going over the specification of the manufacturer is risky, especially when you do not keep track of the battery age with a universal charger.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Elliot Alderson and Jeroen3
I don't know if my charger has that function or not but I guess it doesn't have.
Can I charge the 18650s in 1.9A to 4.3V? Because I want them stay as long as possible
thanks

Comment: @tempo3010 You can charge them at a rate that does not create heat. Get a charger that can measure the charged capacity, or perform a calibration run, to estimate the battery status.

Comment: 4.3 V is also too high.

Comment: 4.3 will dramatically shorten battery life. The trend now is going lower. 4.1 or even 4V. You give up some capacity, but you gain cycle life.